# Entity Framework DB Migration Script

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, scripting, migration

Okay, so this is my situation. I have generated POCOs from a db and developed around them. I have also renamed and changed some of these POCOs to be more readable. I have now made changes to my original db scheme and need to migrate the changes back to my models without overriding my changes except where the scheme has changed. It there a way to generate a *.sql script to hand to by DBAs? If so, it there a way to compare two dbs and generate a change script? ie - dev db => prod db.

Comment: Are you doing code first or database first? There is a schema compare in VS2013. http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: It started as db first and now it is mixed.

Comment: Yuck. If it's database first just propagate the changes down. The way to prevent overriding is to use partial classes (http://dzapart.blogspot.com/2011/11/creating-common-partial-class-with.html). If it's code fist you can generate scripts for the DBA.

Comment: What if I only use code first approach from now on, can I generate this script? Or does it have to start that way? If it is possible can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch a project to code first and generate the scripts you need via migrations. See the link below for a guide on moving from db first to code first, but it sounds like you may be partially there already.

1) `enable-migrations` for the project with your context if you haven't already.

2) create a baseline migration. EF will use this as a starting point so you won't get a bunch of code to create the objects that already exist. The ignore changes flag tells EF not to create the existing objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#option1

```
create-migration InitialCodeFirst -IgnoreChanges
```

3) Now modify your schema as you normally would and create a migration:

```
add-migration SomeNewThing
```

4) Create a script for a different database (like PROD) by using -Script. This will not update your database it just creates a script, so I usually run it a second time without -Script:

```
update-database -Script    // creates a script (in VS), but does not apply
update-database            // updates the database your connect string points to
```

5) DBA runs script and this will add a record to __MigrationHistory to identify it as being applied.

http://devgush.com/2014/02/24/migrating-a-project-from-database-first-to-code-first/

Here is a useful link on deployment: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Comment: Outstanding information! Thanks again for your help!